# Getting HTTP ERROR 500 after deploying my laravel app on shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel

After I deployed my laravel app on shared hosting, I am getting a HTTP ERROR 500..
I checked my error log file and saw this:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '?' in 
/home/shelterm/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php on line 500
```

```
if (isset($arguments[1]) && is_string($arguments[1])) {
      return $factory->of($arguments[0], $arguments[1])->times($arguments[2] ?? null); 
} elseif (isset($arguments[1])) {
      return $factory->of($arguments[0])->times($arguments[1]);
}
```

The same laravel app works perfectly on my localhost(XAMPP)

PHP Version 7.3.1

Comment: Check the PHP version on the Shared hosting

Comment: Try changing php ver to 7.1

Comment: @marv255
`
if (isset($arguments[1]) && is_string($arguments[1])) {
            return $factory->of($arguments[0], $arguments[1])->times($arguments[2] ?? null);
        } elseif (isset($arguments[1])) {
            return $factory->of($arguments[0])->times($arguments[1]);
        }
`

Comment: Yeah `??` syntax is only working on php7 later version

Comment: php version on shared hosting is 5.6.40 @AdnanMumtaz

Comment: @DanielOzeh Laravel needs latest 7.1.3 version. otherwise it wont work

Comment: Which version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: He have said on comment 5.6.40 @Wolfetto

Comment: i am using laravel version 5.8.27 @Wolfetto

Comment: I have edited the answer according to Laravel 5.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Your Server Panel Home, Look for Software Tab and Select MultiPHP Manager

Go to MultiPHP Manager
Select the domain,
Locate PHP version,
Change the php version to Latest version and apply..

You should see the available Php versions on your shared hosting server, select the Latest and apply

Done

Answer (score 0):

According to the Laravel manual, Laravel 5.8 needs the following requirements:

1. **PHP >= 7.1.3**
2. BCMath PHP Extension
3. Ctype PHP Extension
4. JSON PHP Extension
5. Mbstring PHP Extension
6. OpenSSL PHP Extension
7. PDO PHP Extension
8. Tokenizer PHP Extension
9. XML PHP Extension

So, your problem is the php version you use on shared host.

Comment: okay. I will move it to my other server and get back to you on my progress